# How to launch fullscreen when opening iTerm2?

Tags: macos, iterm2

Is there an option to start iTerm in fullscreen mode? I do not see such option in Preferences. I always want that in fullscreen. How can I configure iTerm2 to open as full screen when launching it.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I found it it's here. Preferences → Profiles See attachment. [image]